# Why does this value in the struct not change at all?

Tags: c#, interface

That's very simple question I believe. Could anybody explain why this code outputs 1000, not 1050

```
public class Program
    {
        public static void Main()
        {
            Bus b = new Bus(1000);
            ((Car)b).IncreaseVolume(50);
            Console.WriteLine(b.GetVolume());
        }
    }

    public interface Car
    {
        int GetVolume();
        void IncreaseVolume(int amount);
    }

    public struct Bus : Car
    {
        private int volume;

        public Bus(int volume)
        {
            this.volume = volume;
        }

        public int GetVolume()
        {
            return volume;
        }

        public void IncreaseVolume(int amount)
        {
            volume += amount;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Because `Bus` is a `struct`. Make it a `class`.

Comment: You are not casting a `class` to an interface - as your question title suggests - but a `struct`.

Comment: thank you, i thought i was dealing with class. Stupid mistake, may be closed.

Comment: There's not even the need to cast, since `Bus` (as a class, not struct) has to implement the method, so calling `((Car)b).IncreaseVolume(50)` is exactly the same as `b.IncreaseVolume(50)`, provided Bus is a class.

Comment: @JohnWillemse: I think the OP knows this and this is a simplified example. Think about a method that takes a `Car` and internally calls `IncreaseVolume` and after calling the method with a `Bus` you call `GetVolume` and the value didn't change and you wonder why.

Comment: @DanielHilgarth Yes, I realize that now. My bad!

Comment: @seeker: I've modified the title to clarify the issue. You can change it again if you want. I think this question might be helpful for future visitors and don't see a reason to close it.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Casting a value type (`struct`)  to an interface boxes the value. So you're invoking the method on the boxed copy of the value, not on the value itself.

Comment: And this can be shown very easily using `object.ReferenceEquals`: The result of `object.ReferenceEquals(b, (Car)b)` will be `false`.

Comment: @DanielHilgarth: That just shows that, when you box a value twice, it creates a new object each time. There's not really a way to check if a value and a reference are the same. Already by definition they are not.

Comment: "Boxes twice" because the parameters of `ReferenceEquals` are of type `object` and passing a value type will already box it?

Comment: @DanielHilgarth: Yes, exactly.

Answer (score 1):

Value types (`struct`) are passed around *by value*, but interfaces are considered to be *reference types* (not value types). Let's see:

```
Bus b = new Bus(1000);
```

Now `b` contains the *value* of a `Bus` with its volume set to 1000.

```
Car c = (Car)b;
```

Now the value in `b` is *copied* and made into a reference type (*boxed*) of `Car`. Now `c` contains a pointer to the boxed copy.

```
c.IncreaseVolume(50);
```

On the reference type, you call `IncreaseVolume`, which is a member of the `Car` interface. It receives the reference to the boxed value. It takes a managed pointer to the value in the box (to make it a value type again).

```
void Car.IncreaseVolume(int amount)
{
    ((Bus)this).IncreaseVolume(amount);
}
```

Now your method will act on the value in the box:

```
public void IncreaseVolume(int amount)
{
    volume += amount;
}
```

Now the method returns. Notice how no operation ever acted on the value in `b`, only on copies of it. So the next statement will print `1000`:

```
Console.WriteLine(b.GetVolume());
```

That's it.

Comment: I'm pretty sure there is no difference between invoking a method on a variable containing a struct, an object containing a struct or an array element containing a struct. There is no need to make a copy of the value first.

Comment: Do you mean the extra variable `Car c`? That's just there for the explanation.

Comment: I mean "It unboxes this value (to make it a value type again) by copying the value from the boxed object." I don't think this happens.

Comment: How can it not? After all, `IncreaseVolume` is an instance method on a value type and therefore expects its `this` to be a value type. The `this` passed to an interface method is a reference type, so it needs to be unboxed.

Comment: The value is inside the box. The method can operate on that, the value does not need to be extracted first. Compare to a struct value in an array element. `var a = new Car[1]; a[0] = new Car(1000); a[0].IncreaseVolume(50); var result = a[0].GetVolume(); // result == 1050`

Comment: On second thought, you may be right. Unboxing takes a managed reference to the value in the box, so the value is not copied.

Answer (score 0):

Although it can sometimes be useful for value types to implement mutating interfaces, such types must be used with extreme care.  The fact that C# pretends that all value types are objects is a bit unhelpful in that regard (in reality, they are things that are *convertible* to `Object`), since it means that there's no way to make the compiler warn about incorrect usage.

Aside from the option of ignoring the interface entirely, it is generally necessary that code which will use a mutating interface type must do one of two things:

1. Cast an instance of the struct to an interface type, and never again cast it to anything other than an interface type, `Object`, or `ValueType`.  In particular, never cast it back to its own type.  Note that casting among different interface or reference types is fine, provided the instance is never cast back to its own type.  This is the most common pattern with things like `List.Enumerator`, which often gets cast to `IEnumerator` and never cast to anything else.

   Never use the struct as the interface type, except by passing it as a constrained generic `ref` parameter to any method which is supposed to modify it.  Code which does this will often be syntactically "clunky", but semantically correct.  The fact that struct assignment can be used to take a snapshot of the struct shape may allow semantics which are not readily or efficiently available via other means, but there are many ways to make mistakes that won't cause compiler diagnostics but won't yield correct behavior.

In most cases, if one will need something to implement a mutating *interface*, the type in question should be a class.  Mutable structs should generally permit mutation only by either modifying the underlying fields directly or by using static methods that operate on an instance passed by `ref`.